# Jquery - Autocomplete ViaCEP em multiplas linhas

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Estou usando o WebService do ViaCEP para fazer o autocomplete da rua em meu formulário de cadastro, porém é um formulário onde 20 linhas, cada linha contém:
CEP + RUA DO condomínio
ao preencher o CEP ele tem que autocompletar a rua apenas referente aquele cep da mesma linha, tentei usando `$("cep").next("rua").val(dados.lougradouro)` e não consegui.

//HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep_streetcond[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="street_streetcond[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep_streetcond[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="street_streetcond[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep_streetcond[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="street_streetcond[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep_streetcond[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="street_streetcond[]"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

//JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cep_cond = $("input[name='cep_streetcond[]']");
    var rua_cond = $("input[name='street_streetcond[]']");

    cep_cond.blur(function() {
        var cep_replace = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');

        rua_cond.val("Buscando...");

        $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep_replace + "/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                $("input[name='cep_streetcond[]']").next().val(dados.logradouro);

            } else {
                alert("CEP não encontrado");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.next()` não encontrará o input da rua, pois next retorna o próximo elemento, que no caso é nenhum, já que o input do CEP é o único elemento dentro da `<td>`.

Para encontrar o input da rua, você precisa retornar até o antecessor em comum dos dois inputs, que no caso é a `<tr>`, com `$(this).closest('tr')`, depois disso você pode localizar o input da rua com `.find("input[name='street_streetcond[]']")`.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var cep_cond = $("input[name='cep_streetcond[]']"); 
    var rua_cond = $("input[name='street_streetcond[]']");

    cep_cond.blur(function() {
        var cep_replace = $(this).val().replace(/\D/g, '');
        var logadouro = $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='street_streetcond[]']");

        logadouro.val("Buscando...");

        $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep_replace + "/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
            if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                logadouro.val(dados.logradouro);

            } else {
                alert("CEP não encontrado");
            }
        });
    });  
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

O código abaixo é um exemplo funcional, vamos entende-lo.

> Todos os nossos campos de cep recebem o atributo "name":"cep".
>
> Adicionamos um evento em todos os elementos com o name=cep.
>
> Quando o evento é acionado pegamos o valor digitado em "cep" e guardamos na variavel "cep" após do replace.
>
> Guardamos o elemento que vai receber a rua do cep informado, para chegarmos no mesmo foi necessário utilizar o parents() buscando as tr's e pegando a primeira que seria a que contém os mesmos, após isso usamos o .find e achamos o elemento de nome "rua"
>
> Com o código que o autor da pergunta adicionou de busca ao cep modificamos apenas para setar no elemento "eRua" após a verificação se existe ou não.

```js
$(() => {
  $('[name="cep"]').on('focusout',function() {
    var cep = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var eRua = $($(this).parents('tr')[0]).find('[name="rua"]');
    $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/" + cep + "/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {
      if (!("erro" in dados)) {
        eRua.val(dados.logradouro)
      } else {
        alert("CEP não encontrado");
      }
    });
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cep"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rua"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Referencias :**

[FIND](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

[PARENTS](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

[GETJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: Muito obrigado!